# Help with proving a trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

I am attempting to prove a trigonometric identity. I have no idea how to do it without performing operations across the equal sign. This is the identity:

$$\frac{\cos(3a)}{\cos(a)}=2\cos(2a)-1$$

And here's what I have:

$$\frac{\cos(3a)}{\cos(a)}=2\cos(2a)-1$$

$$\frac{4\cos^3(a)-3\cos(a)}{\cos(a)}$$

$$\frac{(\cos(a))(4\cos^2(a)-3)}{\cos(a)}$$

$$(4\cos^2(a)-3)=2\cos(2a)-1$$

From here, I am at a loss. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Kinda surprised you knew $cos3a$ but not $cos2a$ in terms of $cos a$

Answer (score 2):

Use $cos2a = 2cos^2a-1$ after the last step.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there: $4cos^2a-3=2cos^2a+2(1-sin^2a)-3=2(cos^2a-sin^2a)-1=2cos(2a)-1$